# Installing Bower globally using npm

Tags: npm, bower

I am trying to install Bower globally and it is installed in the directory of

```
C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower
```

I have added the system path of Path and NODE_PATH to that of above, however when running bower, it still cant find the modules.

the prefix of npm-config is:

```
C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

however later within the the list it states it as 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" (overridden)

Ive run out of ideas of what it could be,

Answer (score 15):

If you using npm, which looks like you are, then use the global flag (run as admin)

```
npm install -g bower
```

Comment: i have and it has managed to install it using the above and it has been installed into the appData/Romaing, however when i run the command "bower" in command prompt it cannot find the command

Comment: try restarting your git bash or command prompt, whichever you're using

Comment: Also, make sure you added npm to your PATH variable. Here's [how](https://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/07/how-to-install-nodejs-bower-and-grunt-on-windows-8/#add-npm-to-the-path)

Comment: restarting my command prompt worked, cannot believe it was that, was trying everything for an hour. Thanks alot

Comment: No problem. Whenever you add anything to your environment, it is better to restart the terminal/bash.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes another version or just a wrong path is referenced in the npm config file instead of the installed version.

This may cause node/npm to misplace global modules.

To check and fix:

1. In cmd line type: `npm config list`
   You should get a list of configuration values, one of them is `prefix`.
2. Make sure the path in `prefix` is the same path (only without node.exe) as the actually installed node.exe path.
   (this path is listed further down as `node bin location`)
3. If it's not, change it:

   - Either in the config file (in your user folder, named .npmrc)
   - Or, via cmd line: `npm config set prefix "C:\Program Files\nodejs"` (change path if needed)
4. Reinstall the module/package you tried to install, don't forget -g for global.